# How to define a function parameter to be either of two types

Tags: typescript

How do I make this compile.

```
type Matchmaker = (data: MatcherData, name: string) => string
type MatcherData = RegExp | Array<string>

function makeDataUser(fU: (data: MatcherData) => string): Matchmaker {
    return function (data: MatcherData, name: string): string {
      return fU(data) + name;
    }
}


const user1 = makeDataUser((data: MatcherData): string => {
    if (typeof data === 'regexp') {
        if ("lkajdsf".match(data)) {
            return "yes";
        }
        return "no";
    } else {
        return data.join('');
    }
});

const user2 = makeDataUser((data: MatcherData): string => {
    if (typeof data !== 'regexp') {
        return "yes";
    } else {
        return "no";
    }
}


const mRegexUser = user1(/regex/, 'name');
const mArrayUser = user2(['lkajf'], 'name2');
```

I want a function parameter to be either of two types and use it in either case.

The trick is I know `user1` always expects `RegExp`, and `user2` always expects `Array<string>`. But I want to provide them with a generic function above.

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBzPbN) what you're looking for?  If not, please consider modifying the question to elaborate on what exactly the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you switch the order of checking the type of `data` in the `Matchmaker` functions, the compiler will be able to narrow the type. You need to narrow it to either is array or is not array first, since as you found there is no `typeof <regexp type>`.

```
const user1 = makeDataUser((data: MatcherData): string => {
  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    return data.join("");
  } else {
    if ("lkajdsf".match(data)) {
      return "yes";
    }
    return "no";
  }
});

const user2 = makeDataUser((data: MatcherData): string => {
  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    return "no";
  } else {
    return "yes";
  }
});
```

If you later have more complex types, you could consider using a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), where you choose a key property (`type` below) to tell the compiler how to differentiate (discriminate) between the different branches of the union.

```
type Matchmaker = (data: MatcherData, name: string) => string;
type MatcherData =
  | {
      type: "RegExp";
      value: RegExp;
    }
  | {
      type: "Other";
      value: Array<string>;
    };

function makeDataUser(fU: (data: MatcherData) => string): Matchmaker {
  return function (data: MatcherData, name: string): string {
    return fU(data) + name;
  };
}

const user1 = makeDataUser((data: MatcherData): string => {
  if (data.type === "RegExp") {
    if ("lkajdsf".match(data.value)) {
      return "yes";
    }
    return "no";
  } else {
    return data.value.join("");
  }
});

const user2 = makeDataUser((data: MatcherData): string => {
  if (data.type === "RegExp") {
    return "yes";
  } else {
    return "no";
  }
});

const mRegexUser = user1({ type: "RegExp", value: /regex/ }, "name");
const mArrayUser = user2({ type: "Other", value: ["lkajf"] }, "name2");
```